# Facebook comments box api event call

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have Facebook comments box api on my webpage. So, I want to callback an alert function that when visitor comment on my webpage using Facebook comments book api visitor get the message or at-least the use will redirect to new page after comment. Is it possible? Because I never used this api before so I want help. Kindly let me know your solutions.

Regards

Code by Facebook:

```
  (function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); 
  js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5&appId=559989757482877";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

HTML by Facebook:

```
  <div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/" data-width="100%" data-numposts="6"></div>
```

I am Trying:

```
  FB.Event.subscribe('comment.create', function(response) {
    alert("Thank You.. Redirecting you now...");
    // window.location = "http://google.com";
});
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried. :) It would be easy for us to help you that way.

Comment: @bozzmob I have updated my code kindly check that